# AWS CloudWatch Unified Agent Log Retention

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm running the newer CloudWatch Unified agent on ElasticBeanstalk (EB). Since EB uses the older agent I've disabled EB logging and am using EB extensions to install, configure and run the new agent.

My problem is I don't see a way to set the retention of the cloudwatch log group created. I've gone in several times after deployments and set the retention to 60 days, but it seems like after each deploy or each time the EB application scales up that the setting gets reset to 7 days and we loose log data.

I have looked at the docs and I don't see a way to configure the log retention. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html

Has someone else solved this?